# Why PHP does not have class access modifiers?

Tags: php, class, access-modifiers

Is there a particular reason why PHP does not support class access modifiers and all classes in PHP are considered public ?

Comment: Perhaps you should ask the core PHP development team, as nobody else is likely to be able to give you the answer

Comment: There was (I believe) an RFC about this a while back, don't know how it panned out as I wasn't really following that one

Comment: [Looks like this was the RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/nested_classes). It was withdrawn, but I can't see any explanation about why

Comment: so what would and could you do currently with a class access modifier in PHP?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve that requires this technique? Do you want 'nested' classes or equivalent?

Comment: I do not have a particular problem to solve. I was just curious about this issue since there are several OOP languages like Java that support private modifiers in classes and PHP does not.

Comment: @SiimKallari - It actually has some uses for library developers, allowing us to write internal classes that can't be accessed from outside of the library's public access points/classes/methods